# Algebraic transformation of equations

Tags: equation-solving

From an analytical computation I get an equation `G1`:

```
G1 = Sum[ (Log[y[i]] - u) / s^2, {i, 1, n}] == 0
```

`Solve` can not handle this equation and find a solution for `u`. Furthermore when writing `G11` as

```
G11 = s^2 G1
```

`G11` is essentially returned unevaluated. Mathematica can not be convinced to multiply the `s^2` term into the equation -- which would be perfectly OK for all `s != 0`. I then used a different approach:

```
G12 = G1 //. s -> 1
```

which produced the desired result:

[image]

Mathematica still can not solve this equation for `u`.

Note: for simplicity I used `u` above instead of `μ`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Here is your equation:

```
eq = Sum[(Log[y[i]] + u)/s^2, {i, 1, n}] == 0;
```

This solves it:

```
sl=Solve[MapAt[Distribute, MapAt[Apart, eq, {1, 1}], 1], u]
```

[image]

You may then want to also cancel `s^2`:

```
sl /. Sum[Times[a_, Log[y[i]]], {i, 1, n}] ->a*Sum[Log[y[i]], {i,1,n}]
```

[image]

Done. Have fun!